# My question has been migrated and I need help

Tags: feature-request, support, migration

Hello,

I asked a [question in Stack Overflow and it has been migrated to programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57064/best-practices-for-logging-and-tracing-in-net). I pretty much think my question fits well right here in stack overflow, but that's for another discussion.

When I tryed to comment the answer I had just received for my question, I found out I couldn't, because I don't have a programmers.stackexchange account. But is that so? Shouldn't my account have been automaticaly associated/created in programmers.stackexchange? And what about the stats I have here in Stack Overflow? Do they account for anything in programmers.stackexchange?

Also, since that was the first time one of my questions got migrated, it would have been most useful to have received an e-mail explaining me about the process, and telling me what should my next steps be. Forgive me if this information is available somewhere and I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An account won't be automatically created on Programmers for you - you need to create an account there yourself manually. Remember to choose the same OpenID provider as your account on SO. After you've created your account, check the 'accounts' tab to see that the accounts have been linked correctly.

After a while (the script runs daily I believe), the system should automatically associate the question (together with the reputation gained due to upvotes) to your account. If this does not happen after a day or two, flag the question for mods or open a question on Programmers Meta.

As for your reps, if you have 200 reps on Stack Overflow (which you do not have currently), you will automatically gain a 100 rep bonus when you create your account on Programmers. Since you do not, you can still get the 100 bonus after you reach 200 reps on SO by re-associating the accounts.

Remember that you can always comment on your own question.